# Android System [UID] 1000 Root Permission Request

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, root-access, superuser

Is Android System [UID] in your list of SU Root Permissions?

I just reloaded the stock rom then installed SuperSU (otherwise blank system)

Upon the next restart, one of the permission request that popped up is Android System [UID]. : system_user_1000

I don't remember seeing this before...
[image]

This is normal? Could this be malware?

Answer (score 1):

It may due to Wanam Xposed 2.4.7. An [XDA post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=47743904&postcount=4) states:

> the new Wanam Xposed v2.4.0 did Auto activate "Disable Knox notifications" when Knox Apps are installed. With 2.4.1 he Removed "Knox disabling at boot".

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. I did that for you; however, you might want to check if the version information you gave is correct. The problem described was, according to the XDA post, solved with v2.4.1 of the Wanam module (so *SuperUser* should no longer be triggered by this with a more recent version). Good find, though :) Thanks!

Comment: Aside from SuperSU, The system is blank .

Comment: This is not the answer for this question. Wanam is not installed.  As mentioned in the question, the system is blank.

Answer (score 0):

This is okay. It's not seems to be a malware.

Android_System has to run with su permission. SuperSU is just "being nice" to notify you that.

and, as u told

> installed SuperSU (otherwise blank system)